# Devart.Data.MySQL Entity Provider

Tags: entity-framework-6, devart, llblgenpro, llblgen

I'm having an issue getting Devart.Data.MySQL set up as an Entity Provider.

What I have reached so far is this App.config: https://paste.mozilla.org/Q81ctALe

But all that does is throw this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Entity Framework provider type 'Devart.Data.MySql.Entity.MySqlEntityProviderServices, Devart.Data.MySql.Entity.EF6' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Devart.Data.MySql' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application.
```

At this point I'm out of ideas - any suggestions?

Comment: Your pastebin link is a 404 error.  Probably better to include the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of the Devart Entity Data Provider with Entity Framework v6 is described at https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/?EF.html.

Notes:

- the Entity Framework support is available in the [Professional edition](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/editions.html) of dotConnect for MySQL, its installation includes the required assemblies
- we recommend you to use Entity Developer (the Devart Entity Model item, *.edml) shipped with the provider instead of EDM Designer (the ADO.NET Entity Data Model item, *.edmx) because *.edml is adjusted for working with MySQL and has [advanced functionality](https://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/ed-vs-edm.html). Additionally, Entity Developer adds registration of EF6 provider in app.config automatically.

If this information doesn't help, submit the request via [our contact form](https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html)